# Link a row in dataTable - PrimeFaces 4.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to link a entire row in [Primefaces Datatable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableHome.jsf) but until now I can't put this to work.

I want that when user click in a row, he click in a link. **My currently code is following:**

```
<p:dataTable id="minhaTabela" tableStyleClass="table table-hover" var="disciplina"
value="#{disciplinaMBean.listaDisciplinasPesquisadas}" widgetVar="resultadosDisciplina" 
rowKey="#{disciplina.id}" selection="#{disciplinaMBean.disciplinaSelecionada}"
selectionMode="single" emptyMessage="Nenhuma disciplina encontrada." >

    <p:column headerText="Nome" styleClass="pull-left">
        <h:link outcome="edit.jsf" styleClass="various fancybox.ajax" value="#{disciplina.nome}" />
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

But this code just work if I click exactly above the text, if I click in the middle of the row, the row is selected but nothing happens (as expected, because I didn't program this). So, I need that when I click in any part of the row, a link will be called ("edit.jsf").I need make a fully clickable row.

**How can I do that? What can I do to solve my problem?**

### Edit:

I solved the issue unselecting rows, now when I click in a row, in the same moment the row is "unselected". Now this works almost as initially expected! (Why Primefaces developers don't just add a attribute like "clickOrSelect" to dataTable? Well, if anyone need the code, please tell to me).

The first question still unsolved, waiting for answers :)

Comment: You can call action methods when row selection happens via ajax. Have you tried performing a redirection when that happens?